# Importing XMP Metadata into attributes fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, image, exif

I would like to import EXIF & metadatas of JPG images into QGIS.
For each image, a vector were created by 'ImportPhotos' pluggin, it adds some EXIF into attributes fields but some importants EXIF informations are missing.

In fact, I need 3 more fields. The XMP tags  I need are: `GimbalYawDegree`, `FlightYawDegree`, `RelativeAltitude` value are `real`. That's why I've created 3 new columns (attributes fields) named: `GimbalYawDegree`, `FlightYawDegree`, `RelativeAltitude`.

I would like to create a python script to run a batch for every feature (img imported by ImportPhotos) of a layer. The task would :

- import the XMP datas of images stored at the path located into the attribute field named "Path"

  ```
  import PIL.ExifTags
  exif = {
      PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
      for k, v in img._getexif().items()
      if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
  }
  ```

This code should read the EXIF but this is my first experience in Python and I'm not able to finish the job.

there few samples of images including GimbalYawDegree, FlightYawDegree, RelativeAltitude tags 
https://we.tl/t-BjPuzBGMRc

Comment: This is using only python, but I think this will help you to obtain the information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image

Comment: @Jhon Galindo thanks for this answer it definitly helps as it resolves the "Reading EXIF" part of the code. Now I have to build the second part: importing these datas into as attributes for every features (image imported by ImportPhotos) in a layer. But with my null knowledge in Python, it is going to be funny xD

Comment: For Time field, if you change 'Widget Type' as 'Text Edit' in 'Layer Properties > Attributes Form'. Then you'll see Time value in 'form view'.

Comment: @Kadir Şahbaz Ok so I can conclue that my "Time" issue is a format issue caused by ".000" at the end of my value right? I also can see the format .000 at the end of the field Timestamp. What would be the "best practice" to correct this format to be able to read/use the Time as value as we use to?

Comment: With the new information, please try to improve the post to focus in just one issue, what have you tried and where are you stuck.

Comment: I've edited my original demand, hope it is clear

Comment: Your question is too broad. Because exif data has different types (string, date, time, integer, decimal, etc.). And all should be handled one by one. ImportPhotos plugin works in that way for fields which it adds to attribute table. Maybe a solution is proposed for only one or two exif data which is not added by ImportPhotos plugin. And then you customize the script for the others.

Comment: I've edited again my original demand in regard to your last post.
Datas I need are XML Tags and are real type of value.

Comment: I've been trying for hours. I can't provide a solution without sample image includes `GimbalYawDegree, FlightYawDegree, RelativeAltitude` tags.

Comment: there few sample of image with including GimbalYawDegree, FlightYawDegree, RelativeAltitude tags 
https://we.tl/t-BjPuzBGMRc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PIL Solution**

Add three new fields (real type) named "fyd", "gyd", "ra" (fyd: FlightYawDegree, gyd: GimbalYawDegree, ra: RelativeAltitude)

Copy/paste the script to QGIS Python Editor (not to Console), **select layer** (important) and run.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

layer = iface.activeLayer()
dpr = layer.dataProvider()

fyd_ind = layer.fields().indexFromName("fyd")
gyd_ind = layer.fields().indexFromName("gyd")
ra_ind  = layer.fields().indexFromName("ra")

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    file_path = feature["Path"] 
    print(file_path)

    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        s = str(f.read())

    start = s.find('<x:xmpmeta')
    end   = s.find('</x:xmpmeta')
    xmp   = s[start:end+12].replace("\\n","\n")
    tree  = ET.XML(xmp)

    fyd = tree[0][0].attrib['{http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}FlightYawDegree']
    gyd = tree[0][0].attrib['{http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}GimbalYawDegree']
    ra  = tree[0][0].attrib['{http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}RelativeAltitude']

    dpr.changeAttributeValues({  feature.id():{fyd_ind: fyd,
                                               gyd_ind: gyd,
                                               ra_ind:   ra}  })

#  Other DJI Tags if you need
#  {http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}GpsLatitude'
#  {http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}GpsLongitude'
#  {http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}AbsoluteAltitude'
#  {http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}GimbalRollDegree'
#  {http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}GimbalPitchDegree'
#  {http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}FlightRollDegree'
#  {http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}FlightPitchDegree'
#  {http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}CamReverse'
#  {http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}GimbalReverse'
```

---

**pyexiv2 Solution**

When you run next script, you'll see all metadata includes EXIF, IPTC, XMP .

```py
from pyexiv2 import Image

image = Image("file_path")
metadata = image.read_all() # returns all metadata (EXIF, IPTC, XMP)
print(metadata.keys()) # prints dict_keys(['EXIF', 'IPTC', 'XMP'])
print(metadata["XMP"]) # prints all XMP metadata keys and values
```

Then, decide tags you want to add, add new fields for them, customize next script, select layer and run the script.

```py
from pyexiv2 import Image

layer = iface.activeLayer()
dpr = layer.dataProvider()

fyd_ind = layer.fields().indexFromName("fyd")
gyd_ind = layer.fields().indexFromName("gyd")
ra_ind  = layer.fields().indexFromName("ra")

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    file_path = feature["Path"] 
    print(file_path)

    image = Image(file_path)
    metadata = image.read_all()
    xmp = metadata["XMP"]

    fyd = float(xmp["Xmp.drone-dji.FlightYawDegree"])
    gyd = float(xmp["Xmp.drone-dji.GimbalYawDegree"])
    ra  = float(xmp["Xmp.drone-dji.RelativeAltitude"])

    dpr.changeAttributeValues({ feature.id():{fyd_ind: fyd,
                                              gyd_ind: gyd,
                                              ra_ind:   ra} })
```

Comment: You should use after using Import Photos plugin.

Comment: Perfect I'm going to try but before I'm trying to read the script and my question is about image_folder. Since the path of every file is already stored (because I've used ImportPhotos), could we avoid to have to change the path manually by using the field Path?

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice that. My mistake.

Comment: another point is the url : http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/
does this function requiert any internet connexion ?

Comment: No. Just `Element Tree`module parses xmp data in that way.

Comment: Ok so I can conclue this method does work with XMP but I can't get classic EXIF like "iso" "shutter speed" "field of view" eg. ? (since it is my first python script, it takes time to me to try the script, that's why I've still not "accepted your answer")

Comment: I guess, EXIF and XMP data are different things. XMP is XML-like data. So that some modules/packages like `exifread` doesn't catch XMP metadata. So they're handled differently. You asked just three of them. I answered in that way.

Comment: It would have been awesome to be able to get also few EXIF like "iso" "shutter speed" "field of view". I will make another post to complete my initial demand. thanks for you help, the solution works very well.